# How to Add Image from FILE or URL

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add Image from FileField or URL CharField (Url) but i've got some issue.
1st > File from URL is uploaded correctly, Name and Image in Models are successfully created but .. Image is not correct (see code below)
2nd > If File is choosen all is perfect !

I get POST value from Name , slugify it and use it to change name of image with extension in both case ...
When I choose an url ... Result for image in Models is : halo/.jpg ... I just want to get back value from file just uploaded from url...

In other words : If URL field is filled ... I use this URL instead of File, If not I use FileField to upload.

Thanks for help

**VIEWS.PY**

```
def createHalo(request):
    form = HaloForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = HaloForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            document = form.save(commit=False)
            document.name = request.POST['name']

            img_url = request.POST['url']
            if img_url != "":
                print(img_url)
                photo = Halo()  # set any other fields, but don't commit to DB (ie. don't save())
                filename = urlparse(img_url).path.split('/')[-1]
                extension = filename.split(".")[-1].lower()
                name = "halo/" + slugify(request.POST['name']) + "." + extension
                # content = urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_url)

                response = requests.get(img_url)
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    photo.image.save(name, ContentFile(response.content), save=False)
                    print(name)
                    # photo.image.name = name
                    # photo.save()
                    document.save()
                    # Halo.save()
            else:
                document.save()

            message = "Image ["+request.POST['name'] + "] ajoutée avec succès !"
            messages.success(request, message)
            return redirect('games:create_halo')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'games/createHalo.html', context)
```

**MODELS.PY**

```
class Halo(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='', storage=fs)

    # Methode d'enregistrement dans la base ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # On check si Object Mot déjà créé
        # On test ensuite si l'image de la base est identique à celle envoyée par le formulaire
        # Si différent on supprime l'ancien fichier pour uploader le nouveau lors de la sauvegarde du modèle
        try:
            this = Halo.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
            if this.image != self.image:
                this.image.delete()
        except:
            this = self

        extension = self.image.name.split(".")[-1].lower()
        self.image.name = "halo/" + slugify(self.name) + "." + extension

        # Si le fichier existe on le renomme avec la valeur du nouveau mot (cas ou seul le mot change ... pas le fichier)
        if os.path.exists(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "/" + this.image.name):
            os.rename(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "/" + this.image.name, settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/halo/' + slugify(self.name) + "." + extension)

        super(Halo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**FORMS.PY**

```
class HaloForm(ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput, required=False)
    url = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Halo
        fields = ('name', 'image', 'url')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found by myself finally ;)
I just modified VIEWS.PY to reorganize and change some variable.
Maybe there is another solution more efficient but this one works ;)

```
def createHalo(request):
    form = HaloForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = HaloForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            img_url = request.POST['url']

            if img_url != "":
                response = requests.get(img_url)
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    photo = Halo()  # set any other fields, but don't commit to DB (ie. don't save())
                    filename = urlparse(img_url).path.split('/')[-1]
                    extension = filename.split(".")[-1].lower()
                    name = "halo/" + slugify(request.POST['name']) + "." + extension
                    photo.image.save(name, ContentFile(response.content), save=False)
                    photo.image.name = name
                    photo.name = request.POST['name']
                    photo.save()
            else:
                document = form.save(commit=False)
                document.name = request.POST['name']
                document.save()

            message = "Image ["+request.POST['name'] + "] ajoutée avec succès !"
            messages.success(request, message)
            return redirect('games:create_halo')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'games/createHalo.html', context)
```